# Transpose data in columns to rows downwards

Tags: vba

I am working on a Excel VBA Project. I have data in an excel file as such (each alphabet in each cell). I have many lines as such and each line will definitely have data in the first 6 cells, with variable number of 2 cells each thereafter.

> a b c d e f g h i j
>
> k l m n o p q r s t

I want to convert it to as such:

```
a b c d e f 
        g h
        i j 
k l m n o p
        q r
        s t
```

How do I transpose the values?

Comment: 'Transpose' is such a simple word, but what it looks like you need is a vba program to do this.  For Excel this is beyond my abilities, but I use vba in Access to do this sort of thing.  You might look for a good book that shows how to use vba with Excell (or Excel with VBA).

Comment: I don't at all understand what you're trying to do. How is the variable determined?

Answer (score 0):

This small macro will take the data from Sheet1 and place it on Sheet2 in a re-organized fashion:

```
Sub DataReOrganizer()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, c1 As Long
    Dim N1 As Long
    N1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    r1 = 1
    r2 = 1
    c1 = 7
    For i = 1 To N1
        s1.Range("A" & r1 & ":F" & r1).Copy s2.Range("A" & r2)
        r2 = r2 + 1
        While s1.Cells(r1, c1) <> ""
            s1.Range(s1.Cells(r1, c1), s1.Cells(r1, c1 + 1)).Copy s2.Range("G" & r2)
            c1 = c1 + 2
            r2 = r2 + 1
        Wend
        r1 = r1 + 1
        c1 = 7
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I have an issue though... if the cell with "g" is blank, it doesn't copy "i" and "j"... how do i fix it?